# RHEL 6.5 openssl

Tags: openssl, rhel

i am not able to use ssh services as i get this error OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 10000003 1000105f.

i tried to remove it using yum remove openssl , then i am getting this error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem, You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest". 
from earlier answers i was able to determine that this is the problem because two different versions got installed.
is there a solution to remove it and reinstall it.

Comment: "two different versions" - how did you install them? By package management via yum/rpm or by GNU-Triathlon "configure;make;make install"?

Answer (score 0):

1. The mentioned number is the internal OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER. For RHEL 6 it is 1000105f.

```
$ grep OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/opensslv.h
#define OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER  0x1000105fL
```

2. Your ssh is build against 10000003, which is actually OpenSSL 1.0.0j (maybe a fedora package?).
3. If you try to remove OpenSSL then yum will resolve all package dependencies. And because OpenSSL is a package dependency it would be removed - if it was not protected. To remove without package deps you can use "rpm -e PACKAGENAME --nodeps". But don't do this with your OpenSSL because it seems to be the right package.

Possible solutions:

In case that you've installed any software "raw" on the filesystem (without yum/rpm package management) you should be sure that you use a clean / standard PATH variable for working with the system's native software.

1. Update ssh to the right RHEL 6 package using "yum upgrade openssh-server".
2. If this fails: Get the packages openssh, openssh-server and openssh-clients from RHN. Install them by "yum install openssh-XXXXX.rpm openssh-server-XXXXX.rpm openssh-clients-XXXXX.rpm" or by "rpm -U PACKAGE-NAMES" (maybe with --force option).

Frank

edit: formatting, greeting, english mistakes

Comment: hi thanks for the answer the problem is that the server is a standalone server running behind a firewall, so yum cannot be used for any package upgrades(downloads and upgrades are blocked without approvals). i tried downloading the packages from the RHN and then using rpm to install, it installed properly but even then the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but could be useful for others.

I've solved this problem with an easy solution. Install synaptic on ubuntu, theorically yumex on fedora (yum install yumex). Here you should find "openssl", and, I hope (I'm on ubuntu so I can't test), you will have the option "reinstall". All is fine after that, without big destruction, big uninstallation and re-installation.
See http://www.yumex.dk/2010/10/reinstall-downgrade-package-in-yumex.html